# STM32 SysTick wioth FreeRTOS

Tags: stm32, freertos, hal

I'm running my FreeRTOS app with 1ms SysTick interval. I would like to change to about 10ms, however, when I change its configuration to 10ms and FreeRTOSConfig.h to 100Hz SysTick, my app ends in HardFault.
Should I change something more?

Comment: Do You use CubeMX? Give us some details, like the chip type, etc.

Comment: Yep, I'm using cube, but free rtos is added manually and running without errors. Code is running on stm32f429 chip.

Comment: How do You change the frequency?

Comment: By changing parameter in HAL_InitTick (actually HAL_SYSTICK_Config which is called inside) and updating configCPU_CLOCK_HZ in FreeRTOSConfig.h. This change is not done during runtime, this is a new build.